# Display a string variable in LaTeX using flutter_tex package (Dart)

Tags: flutter, dart, mathjax, katex

I want to display math equations dynamically:
[image]

Here is the successful output of a LaTeX equation:

```
output.add(
    TeXViewDocument(
      r"""<p> When \(a \ne 0 \), there are two solutions to \(x^2 + bx + c = 0\) </p>""",
      style: TeXViewStyle.fromCSS(
        'padding: 15px; color: black; background: white',
      ),
    ),
  );
```

When I try to pass the String variable "formula" in LaTeX, I can't get it to render:

```
String a = '10';
String formula = ' \(' + a + 'x^2\)';
output.add(
  TeXViewDocument(
    formula,
    style: TeXViewStyle.fromCSS(
      'padding: 15px; color: black; background: white',
    ),
  ),
);
```

How can I get my string variables to be rendered to LaTeX? I have tried using jsonEncode() or some other tricks to work with a raw string but nothing has worked. I checked the flutter_tex documentation but there are no examples passing variables for LaTeX output.

Answer (score 3):

Did you try something like this?

```dart
String a = '10';
String formula = "\\(${a}x^2\\)";
```

Comment: That worked!!! Tried so many different things but I'm glad there was a solution. Much appreciated

Comment: can you please explain how it is working because I am not able to understand where to add "\" , and I also have the same problem I am not able to use the variable inside the strings.